# Bootstrap Modal Dialog off screen with white background

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with this snippet: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/modal-login-with-jquery-effects

Using bootstrap 3.3.6

Two questions:

1. Why is there a white background behind my modal? Or how should I debug this?
2. Why is my modal only centering within that white background? I need it to center in the middle of the screen. 
   [image]

My css:

```
/* #####################################################################
   #
   #   Project       : Modal Login with jQuery Effects
   #   Author        : Rodrigo Amarante (rodrigockamarante)
   #   Version       : 1.0
   #   Created       : 07/28/2015
   #   Last Change   : 08/02/2015
   #
   ##################################################################### */

/*@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);

* {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}*/

#login-modal .modal-dialog {
    width: 350px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -25px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding: 20px;

}

#login-modal input[type=text], input[type=password] {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#div-login-msg,
#div-lost-msg,
#div-register-msg {
    border: 1px solid #dadfe1;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 28px;
    transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
}

#div-login-msg.success,
#div-lost-msg.success,
#div-register-msg.success {
    border: 1px solid #68c3a3;
    background-color: #c8f7c5;
}

#div-login-msg.error,
#div-lost-msg.error,
#div-register-msg.error {
    border: 1px solid #eb575b;
    background-color: #ffcad1;
}

#icon-login-msg,
#icon-lost-msg,
#icon-register-msg {
    width: 30px;
    float: left;
    line-height: 28px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #dadfe1;
    margin-right: 5px;
    transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
}

#icon-login-msg.success,
#icon-lost-msg.success,
#icon-register-msg.success {
    background-color: #68c3a3 !important;
}

#icon-login-msg.error,
#icon-lost-msg.error,
#icon-register-msg.error {
    background-color: #eb575b !important;
}

#img_logo {
    max-height: 100px;
    max-width: 100px;
}

/* #########################################
   #    override the bootstrap configs     #
   ######################################### */

.modal-backdrop.in {
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity: .8;
}

.modal-content {
    background-color: #ececec;
    border: 1px solid #bdc3c7;
    border-radius: 0px;
    outline: 0;
    margin: 15% auto;
    position: relative;
}

.modal-header {
    min-height: 16.43px;
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
}

.modal-body {
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
}

.modal-footer {
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    text-align: left;
    border-top: 0px;
}

.checkbox {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.btn {
    border-radius: 0px;
}

.btn:focus,
.btn:active:focus,
.btn.active:focus,
.btn.focus,
.btn:active.focus,
.btn.active.focus {
    outline: none;
}

.btn-lg, .btn-group-lg>.btn {
    border-radius: 0px;
}

.btn-link {
    padding: 5px 10px 0px 0px;
    color: #95a5a6;
}

.btn-link:hover, .btn-link:focus {
    color: #2c3e50;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.glyphicon {
    top: 0px;
}

.form-control {
  border-radius: 0px;
}
```

My html:

```
!-- BEGIN # MODAL LOGIN -->
<div class="modal fade" id="login-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" align="center">
                <img class="img-circle" id="img_logo" src="images/hhb.png">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <!-- Begin # DIV Form -->
            <div id="div-forms">

                <!-- Begin # Login Form -->
                <form id="login-form">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div id="div-login-msg">
                            <div id="icon-login-msg" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></div>
                            <span id="text-login-msg">Type in User Name and Password</span>
                        </div>
                        <input id="login_username" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username (type ERROR for error effect)" required>
                        <input id="login_password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Login</button>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <button id="login_lost_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Lost Password?</button>
                            <button id="login_register_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Register</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <!-- End # Login Form -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this. Here is what I did for any one just starting:

- You can use the developer tools to identify where there might be a conflict in your code.
- For me I was referencing two conflicting versions of bootstrap.

Comment: I dunno why your question is getting a negative point, but that turns out to be exactly my problem, thanks